# Can someone suggest some good resources to study "Addition of angular momentum"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, resource-recommendations

Please help me out in finding some good resource to study Addition of angular momentum of quantum mechanics mechanics part in detail which also explains all the mathematics involved.

Comment: Sakruai's book.

Comment: This is done at length in many texts so it would be informative to know what resources es have already been consulted, and at what level.